# hook. va_list .is possible?

Tags: c++, c, hook

I'm trying to intercept(hook) a function that uses a list of arguments to get the result, and then call the old function.

```
// int __cdecl Ordinal578(char *a1, unsigned int a2, int a3, char a4)  (HEXRAYS)
typedef int(__cdecl *Ordinal578)(char *a1, unsigned int a2, const char * a3, ...);
Ordinal578 Ordinal578org = nullptr;
Ordinal578 Ordinal578ptr = nullptr;

int __cdecl Ordinal578my(char *a1, unsigned int a2, const char * a3, ...)
{

    int result = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, a3);
    result = Ordinal578ptr(a1, a2, a3, args); // if replace this on "vsnprintf_s(a1, a2, a2, a3, args);" it works 5-10 min and then crash!
    va_end(args);

    return result;
}
```

Program crashes after call: **Ordinal578ptr (a1, a2, a3, args)**

How to set the hook on these functions?

Comment: `Ordinal578 Ordinal578ptr = nullptr;` do you initialize this somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure you've got the correct size for the second parameter to `Ordinal578`?  Google turns up declarations using `size_t`, but I'm not sure if they're in 64-bit or 32-bit compilations.  You do realise `vsnprintf_s` has all sorts of [weird error handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3xd30zz.aspx)? - maybe you're hitting a too-small buffer after 5-10 minutes and it's crashing because you're not setting/handling the error reporting, while `Ordinal578` didn't generate such errors in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

1. See if there is a similar function accepting a `va_list` instead.
2. There is no other standard conforming way. Some compilers support magic extensions for va_list, which might do what you want. Look at your compilers manual. For gcc, look at: `__builtin_apply_args ()` and friends.